# Windows media player missing?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-media-player, mtp

I am trying to connect my phone via MTP connection on windows 10 but it isn't detected. I have downloaded windows media pack for windows N edition but this still didn't solve my problem. I tried running the installation a second time but it says the update is already installed. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I was installing the wrong update version. The correct one was KB3133719